# C# sorting values with respect to time

Tags: c#, time, delay, minute

i wanted to create a program like this .
For every minute the time should be printed in the format of 
`h:m` .
For every 5 min it should print "break" 
this should continue for 24 hours ..
like this 
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
0:4
break
0:6
0:7
0:8
0:9
break
0:11
.
.
.
23:59

i came with a program that solves it ..but i never used `DateTime` or any time function , i just used `Thread.Sleep` to dalay printing for 1 minute every time ...
i wanted to use some other method other than `Thread.Sleep` to solve it ...
so please guide me .. (sorry for my Bad english)

this is how i did with `Thread.Sleep` .
please provide me with any other solutions

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class try22
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<24;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<60;j++)
            { 
                if(j%5 != 0 || (j == 0 && i == 0))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(20);        
                    Console.WriteLine(i+":"+j);
                }
                else if(j%5 == 0 )
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                    Console.WriteLine("break");
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

thanks guys i came up with the solution of using actual dates instead of array numbers in my problem

im getting weird errors with timer ..  :( so i used thread.sleep itslef

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class try22
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
        dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("0:0", "H:m",null);
        int cford=dt1.Day+1;
        for (; dt1.Day!=cford; )
        {
           dt1 = addm(dt1);
           Console.WriteLine(dts(dt1));
           Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }
    }
    public static string dts(DateTime dt)
    {

        string tmp = dt.ToString("H:m");
        if (dt.Minute % 5 == 0)
            return "BREAK";
        else
            return tmp;
    }
    public static DateTime addm(DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.AddMinutes(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's FizzBuzz.  This ought to be interesting.

Comment: If this is a homework or interview question, please mark it as so.

Comment: interview question ,i solved with thread.sleep .

Comment: sorry i dont know exactly how stackoverflow functions ,,how and when people answer ,, this is my first question here :p

Comment: My instinct was that this was a bit "do my work". However the OP has shown an example attempt, and is asking for direction on how this could be improved, so I think this is probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which of these were you asked for?

1. Show the current time once per minute
2. Show the current time at the start of every minute like an alarm

Assuming 1, here's a couple of hints in the right direction (which should be helpful either way):

1. You can get the current date and time as a `DateTime` object using [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)
2. `DateTime` objects can return custom string output using `.ToString("format")`.
3. Format is specified with a [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). For example, to get the current hour in 24-hour time (without leading zeroes) you could use `DateTime.Now.ToString("H")`.
4. As per the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), you can include a string literal (unprocessed string) in your format. For example `DateTime.Now.ToString("'Hour is: 'H")` would return `Hour is: 6`
5. You can get the "minute" value of a `DateTime` object as an `int` using `.Minute`. For example, `int minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;`
6. If you want some code to run periodically, one way is to move it into its own method then setup a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) like this:

   ```
   void SomeMethod(object state) { /* DO STUFF HERE */ }

   // Initialise the timer in your main() method 
   // As per MSDN for System.Threading.Timer, first number (0) is start delay.
   // Second number (60000) is interval in milliseconds (60 seconds)
   // This will cause SomeMethod to be called once every 60 seconds starting now.
   Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SomeMethod), null, 0, 60000);
   ```
7. You will need to stop your application exiting straight away after making the `Timer` (otherwise it will never get to run). One easy way to do this in a command line application is place a `Console.Read()` at the end of your `Main()` method which will wait for user input.

Comment: Cool - let me know if you need any further details. If you find it useful please upvote (and potentially mark as accepted answer if it gives you what you were after).

Comment: vote up requires 15 reputation :P 
anyways i will upload the complete code done as u mentioned.

Comment: Good stuff. You should probably make your `for` loop a `while` loop as that's how you're using it. Also you don't need `addm` to be a method (you could just have `dt = dt.AddMinutes(1);`) but there's nothing wrong with the way you've gone. As far as the timer approach, `Thread.Sleep` probably serves your purposes here, but I'm curious why the timer didn't work for you. I'll post how I'd have done it shortly just as a point of curiosity.

Comment: My code isn't a whole lot different from yours when it comes down to it, and I reckon your solution is probably better than a timer given your requirements, so I'll leave it at that. Good stuff :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have used Timer instead of Thread

```
 class Program
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        static int j = 0;
        static int i = 0;
        public static void Main()
        {         
            // Create a timer with a Minute interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);

            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

            // Set the Interval to 1 Minute (60000 milliseconds).
            aTimer.Interval = 60000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
            Console.WriteLine(0 + ":" + 0);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is 
        // raised.
        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {            
            j++;
            if (j == 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("break");
                j = 1;
                i = i + 1;
            }
            if (i == 24)
            {
                i = 0;
            }

            if (j % 5 != 0 || (j == 0))
            {                              
                Console.WriteLine(i + ":" + j);
            }
            else if (j % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("break");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: great ! tnx for the help dude ... now i clearly understand how to use Timer ...ty

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure weather you want to use actual System time to start with or just the time since program execution started. Solution i am posting uses time since program started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
 {
    TimeSpan tt;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(p.run));
        t.Start();
        while (true) ;
    }

    void run()
    {
        tt=new TimeSpan(0,1,0);
        //Timer interval decides when even will be fired.
        Timer t = new Timer(60000);
        t.AutoReset = true;
        t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
        t.Start();

    }

    public void t_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tt.Minutes % 5 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Break");
        Console.WriteLine(tt.Hours.ToString()+":"+tt.Minutes.ToString());
        tt = tt.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @1and0 You can add conditional check for `tt.Minutes ==0` if you dont want it to print break for condition `tt.Minute==0`.

Comment: yep i did that 
i also used object.day!= object.day+1 to stop the operation within 1 day .

Comment: This code's a bit tricky. It creates an instance of itself and starts that in another thread (why?). For the actual functionality ignore the main() method, and what you have is: Given "tt" is your "timeElapsed" variable set "tt" to be 1 minute, set a timer to fire every minute, every minute when that timer fires update "tt" by another minute. It gets the job done I guess.

Comment: @Graphain Well comments on the question suggested that this question is from an interview hence i thought of adding one more concept i.e. threading to enhance this learning activity!